# EWS: How to use Searchfilter for Recurrence End Date

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

i need a list of calendar items which delivers all current items since now.

my searchfilter looks like this:

```
ExchangeService es = getExchangeServiceBinding();

//1000 Objekte werden pro Raum ausgelesen
ItemView view = new ItemView(1000);

List < SearchFilter > searchFilterCollection = new List < SearchFilter > ();
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Now));
```

this delivers all the items since now, but recurrent items which was created in the past and runs in the future doenst show up.

how can i edit my searchfilter to get the recurrent items which starts from the past?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to trigger [recurring item expansion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn727655(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection2). Use the `FindAppointments` method with a `CalendarView`.